# raid 1 with mdadm on whole disks

Tags: mdadm

I successfully created a raid 1 array on my 3TB hard drives with the following command:

```
$ mdadm --create /dev/md0 -v -l 1 -n 2 /dev/sd[bc]
```

I created a luks crypt on that array and moved all of my precious data there and allowed it to fully sync. After /proc/mdstat showed the disk was ready, I unmounted the disk and rebooted. After reboot the raid 1 array had disappeared. I tried to run without success:

```
$ mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sd[bc]
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb
mdadm: /dev/sdb has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

After I created the disk again with the first command, all my data was to my surprise available. After rebooting once again. My disks are lost.

```
mdadm --detail /dev/sd[bc]
mdadm: /dev/sdb does not appear to be an md device
mdadm: /dev/sdc does not appear to be an md device
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. How do I make my raid 1 persist through the system boot.

Comment: I ran the sgdisk zap on my the sd[bc] and rebuilt the array for the third time and I finally got a persistent working array with all of my data still accessible. So all is well now.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sgdisk -Z` on sdb and sdc and rebuild the array with `mdadm --create /dev/md0 -v -l1 -n2 /dev/sd[bc]`.